# SSL certificate, manage domain and subdomain with SAN

Tags: ssl, certificate

We've got a question on the certificate and the SAN part.
Can i put as common name my domain name (eg: example.tld) and use the SAN part to protect my subdomaine (eg: www.example.tld) ?

Actually because the common name used is www.example.tld instead of example.tld we are not protected on example.tld (which is not acceptable).

We could redirect everybody from example.tld to the subdomaine www.example.tld, but we would like to be protected on both domain name.

Is this a common configuration ? Do our certificates company should accepts our requests ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is include all of your domains (example.tld and www.example.tld) in the SAN and the domain that's used by most of your users (most likely www.example.tld) in the Common Name. That will protect all access except access to example.tld from browsers that don't support SAN.

Most certificate companies should support that configuration.

Comment: Thanks for this very fast answer, one last question, when you say:

That will protect all access except access to example.tld from browsers that don't support SAN.

Is it some browser that doesn't support the base domain name as SAN, and can i avoid this by using my base domain name in common name ?

Comment: If you use your domain.tld as the common name then www.domain.tld will get a warning message on browsers that don't support SAN. If a browser doesn't support SAN then there's no way at all to make both domain.tld and www.domain.tld work without a warning -- you have to pick one or the other.